# Is there a list of headers that can be used in an string to compile with NVRTC?

Tags: cuda, nvrtc

(Using  NVRTC run-time compiler)

There is a string of CUDA function:

```
R"(
        extern "C" __global__ void test1(float * a, float * b, float *c)
        {
            int id= blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
            c[id]=a[id]+b[id];
        }
)"
```

that is successfully compiled by driver API into ptx code and used in program to compute c=a+b.

But when I try some header to include an algorithm

```
R"(
        #include <climits>

        extern "C" __global__ void test1(float * a, float * b, float *c, int * gpuOffset)
        {
            int id=blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
            device_vector<int> dv;
            c[id]=a[id]+b[id];
        }


)"
```

it returns an error saying

```
test1.cu(23): catastrophic error: cannot open source file "climits"

1 catastrophic error detected in the compilation of "test1.cu".
Compilation terminated.
```

or

```
test1.cu(28): error: identifier "device_vector" is undefined
```

depending on the include or a header's class (such as device_vector).

Also Documentation shows that both cuFFT and thrust is usable only on host side and it seems I can't use any "partial" algorithm that I wanted to use on each thread-block independently.

Is there a list of headers for some cuda-supported algorithms to be used as per-block:

```
R"(
        #include "driver_api_fft.h"
        #include "driver_api_ifft.h"
        extern "C" __global__ void test1(float * a, float * b, float *c)
        {
            int id=blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
            fft(a,id,1024);
            ifft(b,id,1024);
            c[id]=a[id]+b[id];
        }
)"
```

to successfully compile and run on any target machine or is it possible to link those algorithm libraries(thrust for device_vector) to ptx linker from host-side so that I can use them, somehow, from compiled kernel? If these are not possible, then do I need to write a Fourier-Transform myself and make it "fast" by implementing algorithms myself?

Comment: I don't understand this question at all. The driver API doesn't support JIT compilation of CUDA C code, only PTX. Are you actually asking about compilation of strings via NVRTC?

Comment: Yes, driver API's compilation from string of CUDA C codes.

Comment: I repeat. There is no such thing as driver API compilation of CUDA C code from strings.

Comment: I'm using these functions to do that http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-driver-api/group__CUDA__MODULE.html#group__CUDA__MODULE

Comment: And this http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/nvrtc/index.html#group__compilation_1gc9a66bbbd47c256f4a8955517b3965da

Comment: Then I call cuLaunchKernel to run it(c=a+b) on some arguments(a,b,c) after loading module.

Comment: They don't do that though. They are for linking at runtime, and they can only accept strings of PTX or precompiled code objects from nvcc or another toolchain. You cannot compile CUDA C using those.

Comment: Right so you *are* using NVRTC. That isn't the driver API and it isn't uding the driver API to compile C code, because that isn't supported

Comment: Does this mean, no CUDA specific algorithm headers for NVRTC (fft, sorting and similar basic algorithms)?

Comment: What CUDA components are or aren't available to use in kernel code (however you choose to compile it) is fully described in the Toolkit documentation